# Store additional info with button

Tags: java, android

How can I attach additional information to a button programmatically? I can mButton.setText("new text") to change the text but I want to be able to add a few more fields so that when you click the button you can grab those extra fields and use the data. How might I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use View.setTag(int key, Object tag).

You can retrieve it later with getTag(int key).

In your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id"
        name="string_key" />
    <item type="id"
        name="boolean_key" />
</resources>
```

In your code:

```
//I'd like to store String s and Boolean b in the button.
button.setTag(R.id.string_key, s);
button.setTag(R.id.boolean_key, b);

//Now, I'd like to retrieve the data in new fields.
String new_s = (String) button.getTag(R.id.string_key);
Boolean new_b = (Boolean) button.getTag(R.id.boolean_key);
```

Comment: When I try that, I get an IllegalArgumentStatement, "The key must be an application-specific resource id."

Comment: My mistake! The ID needs to be declared in xml to ensure it is unique. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id" for details.

Comment: Also, if you only need to store one field, you can just use setTag(Object tag) and getTag() - but you seem to want to store multiple fields, which is why the id is required.

Answer (score 2):

You can always extend Button class and add the fields and methods you need

Comment: Please don't do this.  Or at least don't ever let me inherit your code and have to maintain and fix it.

Comment: Very easy and convenient to do though. Might be suitable for a one off, on a small scale.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Tag property. assign a string to it[ if you have more than one value use the pipe character (|) and split it later on] or you can assign an object.